# How do I deserialize a string within a moshi object as its own moshi object?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

I have a JSON object (that I can't change) that passes some data like so:

```json
{
  "title": "foo",
  "actions": "[
    {
       \"label\": \"Hello\"
    }
  ]"
}
```

I'd like to deserialize the whole class with Moshi like so:

```kotlin
data class(
  val title: String,
  val actions: List<Action>
)

data class Action(
  val label: String
)
```

However, because the `actions` field is wrapped with quotes, Moshi has an issue trying to deserialize a string where it expects an array. Is there any way, such as through an adapter or something, to have it properly deserialize the `actions` string as if it were a json object?

Comment: To clarify, the quotation marks in the Action object are not escaped? That's invalid JSON. Still, Moshi should be able to work around this. I'll take a look in a bit.

Comment: Hm, Moshi doesn't have anything for this. Depending on the context (like if this is being used in a Retrofit Converter), you may have the underlying BufferedSource nearby to pop the quotation mark bytes off yourself. No easy solution for this type of malformed JSON with Moshi's existing API.

Comment: @EricCochran Sorry, the quotes were escaped

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it with this system:

```kotlin
/**
 * A [JsonQualifier] that tells [Moshi] to unwrap a string before parsing it.
 * This is useful for when you have a string that is actually a json object.
 */
@JsonQualifier
annotation class JsonString

/**
 * A [JsonAdapter.Factory] that unwraps a string before parsing it.
 * This factory will apply to anything annotated with [JsonString]
 */
object JsonStringAdapterFactory: JsonAdapter.Factory {

  private class UnwrappingAdapter<T>(
      private val type: Type,
      private val moshi: Moshi
  ): JsonAdapter<T>() {
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): T? {
      val string = reader.nextString()                // Unwrap the string
      return moshi.adapter<T>(type).fromJson(string)  // Parse it as JSON
    }

    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: T?) {
      throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns a [JsonAdapter] for `type` annotated with [JsonString], or null if `annotations` doesn't contain
   * [JsonString].
   */
  override fun create(type: Type, annotations: MutableSet<out Annotation>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
    if (annotations.none { it is JsonString }) return null

    return UnwrappingAdapter<Any>(type, moshi)
  }
}
```

Then just annotate your property with `@JsonString`

Comment: nice. i might even make the `moshi.adapter<T>(type)` call once before the adapter is constructed instead of on every `fromJson` call, but the adapter cache lookup is generally pretty fast, anyway.